# spawn terminal running zsh function from plugin

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

i have a zsh [plugin](https://github.com/babarot/enhancd), thru [zplug](https://github.com/zplug/zplug) installed to `$HOME/.zplug/repos/babarot/enhancd`, and it exposes a function: `__enhancd::cd`.
now, what i would like to be able to do is to spawn a terminal running this zsh function.
i tried running e.g.: `wezterm -e __enhancd::cd`.
this fails however, stating this name could not be found on the `$PATH`.
this makes me wonder: how might one manually ensure such functions get loaded while still being able to invoke those functions from the moment the terminal spawns?

Comment: This seems to be a misunderstaning: You do not run `__enhanced::cd` manually - if the plugin is installed correctly, `cd` is aliased to `__enhancd::cd`; as the intention of the plugin is to enhance the interactive use of `cd`, what is the purpose of executing it on terminal start? Otherwise, check for TERM in your zshrc and call cd there if you detect a terminal.

Comment: @TomRegner thanks for your response. invoking this thru `cd` instead seems fair, altho invoking that when spawning the terminal (e.g. `wezterm -e cd`) also seems not to help ensure the patched command is used. Moving the invocation to `zshrc` works, but leaves the challenge of determining when to trigger this: I tend to want this upon opening a new terminal, yet not necessarily when opening a new tab within an existing terminal. Environment variables such as `$TERM` seem not able to make such a distinction.

Comment: With `-e` the command would be `zsh -c cd`, not `cd` or `enhancd...`; but shells exit after the command given terminates, as do terminals when the `-e` command finishes - I don't find a quick way outside of .zshrc - possibly putting with the terminal checked `cd` in `~.zlogin` and starting `wezterm -e 'zsh -l'`(works in a quick test)?

Comment: @TomRegner thanks for thinking along! `zsh -l` does seem to trigger it that way. unfortunately, it seems not to help distinguish that from opening a terminal running zsh otherwise, which would trigger the login script either way. 